# UNet2DConditionModel.from_pretrained() causes a RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, stable-diffusion

I would like to test the Paper [TEXTure](https://github.com/TEXTurePaper/TEXTurePaper) locally at my place. I have successfully installed all libraries and would like to test the examples.
I am using Windows, a RTX 3060 TI, CUDA 11.6 and PyTorch 1.12.1.
When running I get the error:

> RuntimeError: CUDA is out of memory. Trying to allocate 86.00 MiB (GPU
> 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 7.19 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free;
> 7.31 GiB total reserved by PyTorch) If reserved memory >> allocated memory, try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See the
> documentation for memory management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF.

This is triggered at this point:

```
self.inpaint_unet = UNet2DConditionModel.from_pretrained("stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2-inpainting", subfolder="unet", use_auth_token=self.token, batch_size=1).to(self.device)
```

So far I have tried to set this flag with values down to 128:

`set 'PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=max_split_size_mb:512'`

Also, in the parameters of the method I tried to set the batch size to 1.

Does anyone have another idea I can try?